# python django dict is not defined but actually it is

Tags: python, django

Code I'm working with:

```
class Foo(View):

    def post(self, request):
        form_data = {
            'form': UserRegistrationForm(request.POST),
            'sex': request.POST['sex'],
            'terms': request.POST['terms'],
            }
        if form_data['form'].is_valid():
            user = form_data['form'].save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            user.profile.sex = from_data['sex'] #raise err here
            user.profile.save()
```

This throws **name 'from_data' is not defined**.

Its weired for me, it doesn't work, and this does:

```
user.profile.sex = request.POST['sex']
```

For someone who was used to code in C that situation is little funny and much annoying.

Comment: there's a typo. seems even used to code in C isn't immune to simple typo-causing-3-hours-head-scratching mistakes :)

Comment: I'm stupid 4 more to go

Comment: I once had a typo, took me 18 hours to figure it out. lol

Comment: Nice. We should less stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from_data['sex']
```

should be changed to

```
form_data['sex']
```

Just a minor typo it seems.

Hope that helps